# Pentaho Login Error using LDAP/JDBC Hybrid configuration

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, ldap, pentaho

I've followed Pentaho (version 7) documentation on how to set LDAP/JDBC hybrid configuration: created the tables and filled them with the appropriate values then updated the configuration files as instructed.

When trying to login to the PUC the following error is thrown:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.jcr.LoginException:
LoginModule could not perform authentication: Target of Bean was never
resolved:
org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService
```

My `security.properties` includes

```
provider=ldap
role.provider=jdbc
```

I set the providerName in `pentahoObjects.spring.xml` to **jdbc**

```
<pen:bean id="activeUserRoleListService" class="org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.IUserRoleListService">
    <pen:attributes>
      <pen:attr key="providerName" value="jdbc"/>
    </pen:attributes>
  </pen:bean>
```

`applicationContext-spring-security-jdbc.properties` is properly configured

I set jdbcRoleMap in `applicationContext-pentaho-security-jdbc.xml` to my jdbc admin group

And repalced: `org.springframework.security.ldap.populator.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator`
with:

```
<bean id="populator" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.UserDetailsServiceLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
<constructor-arg ref="jdbcUserDetailsService" />
</bean>
```